# show details record with totaling

Tags: sql-server

I am trying a query for showing detail of the employee salary along with total. But there is an error showing as it is not used "group by". Is there any way to show it. My query is:

```
select EmpName,BasicSalary,GradePay,TA,DA,HRA,Gross,sum(Gross) from tblSalary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select EmpName,BasicSalary,GradePay,TA,DA,HRA,Gross,SUM(Gross) OVER() TOTAL from tblSalary
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [OVER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms189461.aspx) windowing clause in SQL Server 2005 onwards

```
select EmpName,BasicSalary,GradePay,TA,DA,HRA,Gross,sum(Gross) over () TotalGross
from tblSalary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012 you can try do this with `GROUPING SETS` clause.

```
SELECT EmpName, SUM(Gross) 
FROM tblSalary
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (
        ()
        ,(EmpName)
    )
```

It will add one row with total value.